# Update the second element from a list where the first element is in another list

Tags: list, for-loop, scheme

Maybe my title is a little bit messy..

I have a list in this form
(define a '( (1 3) (2 2) (3 3) (4 5) (5 1)))

and I want to decrement by 1, the second element for every pair which has the the first element in the given list...

Eg..
(updateA ( 1 3 4))

will result

( (1 2) (2 2) (3 2) (4 4) (5 1)

```
(define (updateA lst)
      (for ((x lst))
        (for ((y a))
          (equal? x (car y)))
          ;;do something here

  ))
```

Comment: Does it matter to you whether the list that is passed in is actually updated?  E.g., `(let ((l ...)) (updateA l))` will return a _new_ list with the desired structure, but `(let ((l ...)) (updateA l) l)` will return the original list (which hasn't been modified).  Typically, the word “update” when used like this suggests that the argument will be _modified_.  The word _decrement_ (and _increment_) also suggest that something is being modified.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In the Scheme world, update doesn't necessarily imply mutation, unless the word "in-place" is also used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one implementation:

```
(define (decrement-alist-values alist keys)
  (map (lambda (ass)
         (if (member (car ass) keys)
             (list (car ass) (- (cadr ass) 1))
             ass))
       alist))
```

Example:

```
> (decrement-alist-values '((1 3) (2 2) (3 3) (4 5) (5 1))
                          '(1 3 4))
((1 2) (2 2) (3 2) (4 4) (5 1))
```

---

Joshua Taylor mentioned that my version technically didn't update the list via mutation. That is a fair point, so here is a mutating version:

```
(define (decrement-alist-values! alist keys)
  (for-each (lambda (ass)
              (when (member (car ass) keys)
                (set-car! (cdr ass) (- (cadr ass) 1))))
            alist))
```

Example:

```
> (define a `(,(list 1 3) ,(list 2 2) ,(list 3 3) ,(list 4 5) ,(list 5 1)))
> (decrement-alist-values! a '(1 3 4))
> a
((1 2) (2 2) (3 2) (4 4) (5 1))
```

Comment: If this works for @dionysosz, great!  I'd point out though that this is returning a _new_ list with the desired structure;  it's not _updating_ the existing list.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Technically true, but in Scheme, actually mutating stuff isn't recommended anyway, so it's about as good as it gets. I could add a mutating version, though.

Comment: I agree that it's not particularly idiomatic, but it's certainly possible.  I only mentioned this because the OP said _update_ (but then again, also accepted the answer says it's what was looked for).  I added a comment on the question to ask for clarification.  I think the term _decrement_ also suggests modification rather than allocation of a new structure.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Here, I added a mutating version.